# Installing MySQL on El Capitan

Tags: mysql, osx-elcapitan

I am attempting a fresh install of mysql on a new iMac running OSX 10.11. I downloaded the latest 10.10 dmg and followed installation directions, but when I try to run mysql, I get the

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2).

I have spent several hours reading answers here and elsewhere as to how to fix it, and nothing has worked so far.

What I know:

The `/tmp/mysql.sock` file has been renamed `/tmp/mysql.sock.lock`. Apparently, if I could get mysqld to run, it would make a new socket file, but when I try to get mysqld to run (either from the Terminal or System Preferences) it just fails and produces the same error. Likewise, when I try to run mysqladmin it fails and produces the same error.

When I run <kbd>mysqld_safe</kbd>, it produces the following, but doesn’t clear up the socket error:

> 151206 16:40:20 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXXXs-iMac.err'.
>
> 151206 16:40:20 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
>
> 151206 16:42:01 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXXXs-iMac.pid ended

When I ran mysql on Lion, I was always able to clear up socket errors by running mysqld_safe.

Advice?

Comment: I would recommend installing HomeBrew and then running brew install mysql

Comment: Same result. Still can't find the socket.

Comment: did you try mysql.server restart ?

Comment: Don’t install it natively. Develop within a virtual machine.

Comment: did you try running the server with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command 'sudo mysqld' from the command line to launch the server.